# Wireless indicator light flashing for activity on laptop keyboard

Tags: wifi

Here's wireless:

```
$ lspci | grep -i wireless
0d:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
```

OS is Linux Mint 12, using gnome2/compiz.

I've got HP Pavilion dv7 899AW, sandybridge 915 chipset

The problem is that the orange/blue light for the wireless won't stop flashing. Probably flashing due to activity.

I tried this fix, but it didn't work: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1699037&page=3

Also, the mute light stays permanently orange.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the led behavior in files under the `/sys` directory like `/sys/class/net/wlan0/device/leds/*/`. So you can backup those files before changing anything and erase the content of the `trigger` file under the transmission, reception and association directory.

```
echo none > /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/leds/*TX/trigger
echo none > /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/leds/*RX/trigger
echo none > /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/leds/*assoc/trigger
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not going to get a chance to test this for bit, as I'm trying not to break my linux for a bit...

Comment: You are not going to break it. [SysFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) (/sys) is a virtual file system. I already tested and it works fine