# How do I disable wireless on Mint 14?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

This got closed on AskUbuntu because it wasn't Ubuntu enough for them.

I don't have any WLAN connections set up, and I always connect via Ethernet cable. However my computer has a small light on it that flashes to indicate network activity. For some reason this light keeps flashing, at extended random intervals, which is very annoying. I remember that I disabled it somehow on my old partition (Ubuntu, Mate), but I'm not seeing an option for it now.

Added: since asking I found an answer to the LED problem here: "[Wireless indicator light flashing for activity on laptop keyboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25612/wireless-indicator-light-flashing-for-activity-on-laptop-keyboard)" but I would feel slightly better knowing that I solved the source of the problem and not just the symptom.

Then I tried `sudo rfkill block all`. Will that solve it permanently? Is there a better way?

Comment: Remove the firmware and/or blacklist the relevant module...

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: It depends on your hardware (a vital detail you omitted from your question). See the [Arch Wiki Wireless page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Mint is running NetworkManager, and that's what connects your wireless network.

Edit your wireless connection profile, there's an option called `Automatically connection`, disable that.

Comment: Yes, I have NetworkManager. The documentation for it is a huge mess. Does <code>sudo nmcli nm wifi off</code> do what I want? Because nothing in /etc/NetworkManager changed when I ran it.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the config in /var. Just when I think I'm starting to figure Linux out, it turns out to be even more screwed up than I thought. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Wutaz no need to run nmcli, just open `nm-connection-editor` to edit that